# Compiling Android on PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, ant, urbanairship.com

I have recently upgraded to Mavericks OS, I am now seeing errors when trying to run:

```
$ phonegap build android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling Android...
   [error] An error occurred while building the android project.Error executing "ant debug -f "/usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/build.xml"": 
BUILD FAILED
/Applications/android-developer-tools/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Applications/android-developer-tools/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 7 seconds
```

I have had a look at those lines in build.xml:

```
<target name="-compile" depends="-pre-build, -build-setup, -code-gen, -pre-compile">
<!-- line 720 --> <do-only-if-manifest-hasCode elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping...">
        <!-- merge the project's own classpath and the tested project's classpath -->
        <path id="project.javac.classpath">
            <path refid="project.all.jars.path" />
            <path refid="tested.project.classpath" />
            <path path="${java.compiler.classpath}" />
        </path>
        <javac encoding="${java.encoding}"
                source="${java.source}" target="${java.target}"
                debug="true" extdirs="" includeantruntime="false"
                destdir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
                bootclasspathref="project.target.class.path"
                verbose="${verbose}"
                classpathref="project.javac.classpath"
<!-- line 734 --> fork="${need.javac.fork}">
            <src path="${source.absolute.dir}" />
            <src path="${gen.absolute.dir}" />
            <compilerarg line="${java.compilerargs}" />
        </javac>
<!-- continue... -->
```

I have also tried running `$ ant debug` which returns a load of errors shown below:

```
-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 21 source files to /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/bin/classes
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushAutopilot.java:6: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class AirshipConfigOptions
    [javac] location: package com.urbanairship
    [javac] import com.urbanairship.AirshipConfigOptions;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushAutopilot.java:7: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Autopilot
    [javac] location: package com.urbanairship
    [javac] import com.urbanairship.Autopilot;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushAutopilot.java:8: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Logger
    [javac] location: package com.urbanairship
    [javac] import com.urbanairship.Logger;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushAutopilot.java:9: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class UAirship
    [javac] location: package com.urbanairship
    [javac] import com.urbanairship.UAirship;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushAutopilot.java:10: package com.urbanairship.push does not exist
    [javac] import com.urbanairship.push.PushManager;
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushAutopilot.java:15: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol: class Autopilot
    [javac] public class PushAutopilot extends Autopilot {
    [javac]                                    ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushAutopilot.java:41: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class AirshipConfigOptions
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushAutopilot
    [javac]     private AirshipConfigOptions getAirshipConfig(Application application, AirshipOptions configOptions) {
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:5: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Autopilot
    [javac] location: package com.urbanairship
    [javac] import com.urbanairship.Autopilot;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:6: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Logger
    [javac] location: package com.urbanairship
    [javac] import com.urbanairship.Logger;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:7: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class UAirship
    [javac] location: package com.urbanairship
    [javac] import com.urbanairship.UAirship;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:8: package com.urbanairship.location does not exist
    [javac] import com.urbanairship.location.LocationPreferences;
    [javac]                                 ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:9: package com.urbanairship.location does not exist
    [javac] import com.urbanairship.location.UALocationManager;
    [javac]                                 ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:10: package com.urbanairship.push does not exist
    [javac] import com.urbanairship.push.PushManager;
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:11: package com.urbanairship.push does not exist
    [javac] import com.urbanairship.push.PushPreferences;
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:12: package com.urbanairship.util does not exist
    [javac] import com.urbanairship.util.ServiceNotBoundException;
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:48: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class PushPreferences
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]     private PushPreferences pushPrefs;
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:49: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class LocationPreferences
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]     private LocationPreferences locationPrefs;
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushReceiver.java:7: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Logger
    [javac] location: package com.urbanairship
    [javac] import com.urbanairship.Logger;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushReceiver.java:8: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class UAirship
    [javac] location: package com.urbanairship
    [javac] import com.urbanairship.UAirship;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushReceiver.java:9: package com.urbanairship.push does not exist
    [javac] import com.urbanairship.push.PushManager;
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushAutopilot.java:30: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable UAirship
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushAutopilot
    [javac]         UAirship.takeOff(application, getAirshipConfig(application, configOptions));
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushAutopilot.java:32: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable PushManager
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushAutopilot
    [javac]         PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(PushReceiver.class);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushAutopilot.java:36: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable UAirship
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushAutopilot
    [javac]         if (UAirship.shared().getAirshipConfigOptions().pushServiceEnabled && enablePushOnLaunch) {
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushAutopilot.java:37: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable PushManager
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushAutopilot
    [javac]             PushManager.enablePush();
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushAutopilot.java:25: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushAutopilot.java:43: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class AirshipConfigOptions
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushAutopilot
    [javac]         AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(application);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushAutopilot.java:43: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable AirshipConfigOptions
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushAutopilot
    [javac]         AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(application);
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushAutopilot.java:97: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushAutopilot.AirshipOptions
    [javac]                             Logger.verbose("Found " + name + " in config.xml with value: " + value);
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushAutopilot.java:105: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushAutopilot.AirshipOptions
    [javac]                     Logger.error("Error parsing config file", e);
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:60: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]         Logger.info("Initializing PushNotificationPlugin");
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:61: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Autopilot
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]         Autopilot.automaticTakeOff(cordova.getActivity().getApplication());
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:62: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable PushManager
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]         pushPrefs = PushManager.shared().getPreferences();
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:63: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable UALocationManager
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]         locationPrefs = UALocationManager.shared().getPreferences();
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:73: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.error("Error constructing notification object", e);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:99: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.error("Error in raiseRegistration", e);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:110: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]         Logger.info("Sending event " + event + ": " + data);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:119: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.debug("Invalid action: " + action);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:127: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol: variable Logger
    [javac]                     Logger.debug("Plugin Execute: " + action);
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:131: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol: variable Logger
    [javac]                     Logger.error(e);
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:143: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable PushManager
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             PushManager.enablePush();
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:150: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable PushManager
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             PushManager.disablePush();
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:157: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable UALocationManager
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             UALocationManager.enableLocation();
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:164: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable UALocationManager
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             UALocationManager.disableLocation();
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:171: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable UALocationManager
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             UALocationManager.enableBackgroundLocation();
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:178: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable UALocationManager
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             UALocationManager.disableBackgroundLocation();
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:239: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable PushManager
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             String pushID = PushManager.shared().getAPID();
    [javac]                             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:276: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.debug("Returning quiet time");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:288: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable PushManager
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]         Set<String> tags = PushManager.shared().getTags();
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:293: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.debug("Returning tags");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:296: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.error("Error building tags JSON", e);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:303: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable PushManager
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             String alias = PushManager.shared().getAlias();
    [javac]                            ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:316: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.debug("Settings alias: " + alias);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:317: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable PushManager
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             PushManager.shared().setAlias(alias);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:321: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.error("Error reading alias in callback", e);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:338: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.debug("Settings tags: " + tagSet);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:339: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable PushManager
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             PushManager.shared().setTags(tagSet);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:343: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.error("Error reading tags JSON", e);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:356: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.debug("Settings Sound: " + soundPreference);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:359: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.error("Error reading soundEnabled in callback", e);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:372: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.debug("Settings Vibrate: " + vibrationPreference);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:375: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.error("Error reading vibrateEnabled in callback", e);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:388: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.debug("Settings QuietTime: " + quietPreference);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:391: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.error("Error reading quietTimeEnabled in callback", e);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:414: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.debug("Settings QuietTime. Start: " + start.getTime() + ", End: " + end.getTime());
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:418: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.error("Error reading quietTime JSON", e);
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:429: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.debug("LOGGING LOCATION");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:430: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable UALocationManager
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             UALocationManager.shared().recordCurrentLocation();
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:431: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class ServiceNotBoundException
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]         } catch (ServiceNotBoundException e) {
    [javac]                  ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:432: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushNotificationPlugin
    [javac]             Logger.debug("Location not bound, binding now");
    [javac]             ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushNotificationPlugin.java:433: cannot find symbol
    ... removed for brevity ...
    [javac] symbol  : variable PushManager
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushReceiver
    [javac]                 + intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_APID)
    [javac]                                         ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushReceiver.java:74: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable PushManager
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushReceiver
    [javac]                 + intent.getBooleanExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_REGISTRATION_VALID, false));
    [javac]                                          ^
    [javac] /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushReceiver.java:71: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable Logger
    [javac] location: class com.urbanairship.phonegap.PushReceiver
    [javac]         Logger.info("Registration complete. APID:"
    [javac]         ^
    [javac] Note: /usr/vhosts/project/platforms/android/src/com/clinique/byinvitation/Clinique.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 93 errors

BUILD FAILED
/Applications/android-developer-tools/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Applications/android-developer-tools/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 2 seconds
```

Comment: Where is the source code for `com.urbanairship.AirshipConfigOptions` relative to `source.absolute.dir` and `gen.absolute.dir`? Should `AirshipConfigOptions` be a .class file by the time `<javac>` runs?

Comment: I think `com.urbanairship.AirshipConfigOptions` is defined in `platforms/android/src/com/urbanairship/phonegap/PushAutopilot.java`. With your other suggestions, I am not sure where to look for that, I have done a search for `source.absolute.dir` and `gen.absolute.dir` but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

It was all sorted with one line:

```
$ phonegap platform update android
```

I think the reason I was getting this error was because I had just recently upgraded my Mac to Mavericks OS.